# Run task in background in iOS 10

Tags: background, notifications, calendar, ios10

Can one use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` or `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` to run a snippet in background in fixed interval, say once per day, without notifiying user? For example just with playing a sound and the running `custom code`?
I need this to calculate exact time of a special alarm in background everyday and then set notification for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger a block of code to run when the notification is fired.  You can, however, trigger a block of code to execute with a [`UNNotificationAction`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationaction) by adding an action to your notification and using `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)` on `UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter()`.

Comment: How can I run a block of code in background to update alarms if future? The time of these alarms is calculated every morning using a specific algorithm.